# array position objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, nsarray

I have an NSArray. Lets say that i have 3 objects inside it. e.g

```
test (
        {
        Code = A;
        Comment = "None ";
        Core = Core;
},{
        Code = B;
        Comment = "None ";
        Core = Core;
},{
        Code = C;
        Comment = "None ";
        Core = Core;
})
```

I want to search for a 'Code' and return the array index. How can i do this? e.g. locate code 'b' and i would have '1' being returned (since its the second position within the array).

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head so there might be some typos in it. I am assuming the objects inside your array are dictionaries:

```
for (NSDictionary dict in testArray)
{
    if ([[dict objectForKey:"Code"] isEqualToString:@"B"]
    {
        NSLog (@"Index of object is %@", [testArray indexOfObject:dict]);
    }
}
```

You could also use (probably more efficient)

```
- (NSUInteger)indexOfObjectPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate
```

passing a predicate of `@"Code == 'B'"` on the block. This method will specifically return the index of objects passing the test.

Answer (score 0):

If targeting iOS 4.0 or above there are [`NSArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) methods that allow you to do this using blocks.

`– indexOfObjectPassingTest:`
`– indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:`
etc..

```
NSArray *test = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"A", @"Code", @"None", @"Comment", @"Core", @"Core", nil],
                 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"B", @"Code", @"None", @"Comment", @"Core", @"Core", nil],
                 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"C", @"Code", @"None", @"Comment", @"Core", @"Core", nil],
                 nil];
NSIndexSet *indexes =[test indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [[obj valueForKey:@"Code"] isEqualToString:@"B"];
}];

NSLog(@"Indexes with Code B: %@", indexes);
```

Answer (score 0):

In its simplest form I would use the following:

```
- (NSInteger)indexForText:(NSString*)text inArray:(NSArray*)array
{
  NSInteger index;
  [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    YourObject* o = (YourObject*)obj;
    if ([[o property] isEqualToString:text]) {
      index = idx;
      *stop = YES;
    }
  }];
  return index;
}
```